# Why does George Mcfly employ Biff to wax his car after he had previously tried to rape his wife?

Tags: plot-explanation, back-to-the-future

In *Back to the Future*, Marty goes back to 1955 and devises a plan for his father George McFly to win over Lorraine in order to ensure Marty's survival.

The plan involved Marty pretending to sexually assault Lorraine then George would step in and stop him. Biff meddles with Marty's plan, by kicking Marty out of the car and then he tries to rape Lorraine. George expects to find Marty in the car and finds Biff and musters the courage to stop Biff and protect Lorraine.

Near the end of the movie when Marty travels back to 1985 we see that Biff is outside of Marty's house waxing George's car. Why would George employ Biff to do this job? I can't imagine Lorraine would be too happy with the idea.

Comment: Crispen Glover so responsible. The original ending had either Goldie waxing his car or a unnamed black guy waxing the car. Crispen Glover thought it was racist & got them to change it the day of shooting. Look up Crispen interview on YouTube on Opie&Anthony radio show. Ants a huge BTTF fan & asked y sum1 who tried rape his wife was employed & Crispen revealed the OG ending p

Comment: **Without injecting my personal opinion into the matter**, you need to consider that sexual assault (a more accurate description of what we saw happen) hasn't always been considered as heinous as it is today. This means that it wouldn't have been as big of a deal in 1955 as it is today. Furthermore, the BTTF movie is from 1985 and therefore also is created in a time where these topics were less touchy and not considered the epitome of evil (I'm overstating for clarity's sake). This is why e.g. early James Bond can be considered a male chauvinist today, but not **by the old movie's standards**.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

I haven't seen any director commentary, so I can't speak with full authority.

However, I don't think they thought that hard about it.  I think it is put in there for dramatic effect.

The antagonist was defeated, and now instead of the big man on campus, he practically begs from George McFly for work.  It is a triumph of the little guy over his oppressor.

The movie is full of [David vs Goliath moments](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DavidVersusGoliath), and that's when you know the underdog ultimately won.

Comment: No offence, but that link is a really bad one. 'Nearly every Rocky and Jackie Chan movie' it says. Jackie Chan and Rocky Balboa, weak, defenceless underdogs??! Yeah right.

Comment: @poepje: The main article is accurate.  It's community contributed content, so not all of it is going to be accurate.  Feel free to go fix those examples :)

Comment: @poepje The entire Rocky series is about the underdog.

Comment: @poepje - compared to Apollo Creed, Clubber Lange, and Ivan Drago?  Yeah, definitely in the underdog role.  Most people would not consider "can withstand endless brutal beatings" to be a "strength."

Comment: @AndrewMattson This is not about personal favourite actors, nor about comparing them with one another. I can tell you that they're not weak, not defenceless but also not capable of taking endless beatings. Jackie Chan, for one, does all his stunts himself so he must know a fair deal of kungfu. And both are famous and always have leading roles, so saying they're underdogs makes no sense at all.

Comment: If you guys don't like the link, I will link wikipedia instead. If that isn't the case, then please take your discussion elsewhere. This isn't reddit - it is a section for discussing improvements to the contents of this answer. The other page is not this answer.

Comment: @poepje - You know that referring to Rocky, Apollo Creed, Clubber Lange and Ivan Drago is not taking about actors, but the characters in the Rocky movies that Rocky has to fight, who are considered physically and skill-wise much better than him.  They build those characters up to mythical proportions specifically so Rocky can be the underdog.  Your response is pretty much a non sequtur.  Citing Rocky as a non-underdog was not well-thought-out.

Comment: And in 30 years, things have time to settle...

Comment: Bit of necromancy here, but @MerlynMorgan-Graham, they're allowed to question the validity of your references.

Comment: @T.J.L. suggest an edit or stop necroing posts

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham Your statement of "The other page is not this answer" is not true. You've brought the other page in as support for your position. That makes its content relevant. My suggestion is the same as the previous ones - try to support your answer with better references.

Comment: @T.J.L. I have changed this to a community wiki. Maybe you can fix it yourself. I really don't care about this answer at all, and it seems you do. Go for it.

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham Nope; zero interest in fixing an entrenched answer with a flawed premise. Making it a community wiki doesn't have any bearing on whether or not I could change it, nor whether or not it is your answer, nor whether or not it is flawed (despite the votes).

Answer (score 39):

1. It's not clear that Biff was trying to *rape* Loraine.  Although he was clearly taking liberties he should not have.
2. McFly subdued Biff in the fight at the dance.  After that, Biff learned to take his place behind McFly.  The car-waxing scene was really just to prove this.
3. 30 years had passed.  The new, wiser McFly was undoubtedly able to forgive Biff--especially with Biff in his new subordinate role.

Answer (score 10):

For all we know, in the intervening years, Biff saw the error of his ways, begged forgiveness, and was accepted by the McFlys as a changed man.

Answer (score 6):

We're talking about a movie filmed in 1985 set in the year 1955. People's attitudes towards consent were different back then. For example, no one, at least not at the time, would say John Travolta was trying to rape Olivia Newton-John in Grease.

Comment: I don't think this explains why McFly would want to employ Biff, which is what the question asks.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think he *employed* him (as in, offering him money for doing it). I think it is more that he *commanded* him to do it, that is, he's now the one who can get Biff to do things for him, and Biff no longer has the balls to refuse.

Comment: I suspect it is, I got the feeling that Biff was his employee in some respect.  Most adults don't commant (bully) people to wash their cars. It also would have been a poor reflection on George if he was after turning into a bully.

Comment: I think Biff actually owned his car-waxing business and George was his customer, at one point he is showing off the promotional match-books he got made. The scene was more to show that Biff was now the subservient one.

Answer (score -8):

Have you ever noticed how feminine Biff's character is in the new 1985? The assumption the audience is being invited to make is that, because he was so completely emasculated in his encounter with George McFly the night of the dance, Biff eventually became a homosexual. This explains why George McFly doesn't consider it a risk to keep him around the house despite his past misdeeds.

Comment: -1; I don't agree with this assessment at all. If you can offer specific evidence (tropes, allusions in the movie to interest in males, specific manner of dress considered homosexual in 1985, specific behavior considered FEMININE and not just submissive in American culture in 1985, etc) of him being explicitly depicted as homosexual, I'll remove my downvote. Until then I will just assume it is just your personal concepts and stereotypes speaking rather than any evidence in the movie.

Comment: [citation needed]

Comment: A reversal of the dominant relationship that Biff had over George had does *not* make him homosexual now.  This is borderline offensive in all honesty ... equating homosexuality to submissiveness.